# Two interdependent member functions with no default constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, initialization

I am sure that this question must be answered somewhere, but I cannot formulate the question...
My issue is that I have two objects (`foo`, `bar`), where `bar` needs to be initialized using `foo` instance. How to do it, when both objects are data members of another class (`baz`)?

I cannot initialize `bar` in `baz` constructor body as `bar` in this time must have been already initialized using default constructor that it is missing.

I cannot initialize `bar` in `baz` initializer list as `foo` has not been constructed in this time. Watch out as compiler does not care!

See the example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

class foo
{
   public:
      foo() {
         cout << "foo constructor called." << endl;
      }

   private:
};

class bar
{
   public:
      bar(foo inFoo) : mFoo(inFoo) { 
         cout << "bar constructor called." << endl; 
      }

   private:
      foo mFoo;
};

class baz
{
   public:
      baz() : mBar(mFoo) { 
         cout << "baz constructor called." << endl; 
      }  // ERROR: mFoo is not inizilized

   private:
      bar mBar;
      foo mFoo;
      
};

int main()
{
   baz Baz;
}
```

Only workaround that comes to my mind is using pointers in the `baz` class. Using of a pointer for `bar` data member allows me to postpone initialization until `baz` constructor body.

```
class baz
{
   public:
      baz() {
         cout << "baz constructor called." << endl;
         mBar = unique_ptr<bar>( new bar(mFoo) );

      }

   private:
      unique_ptr<bar> mBar;
      foo mFoo;

};
```

But is it possible to solve this problem without pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `mBar` depends upon `mFoo`, just reorder the declarations:

```
private:
    foo mFoo;
    bar mBar;
```

and initialize `mFoo` first:

```
baz() : mFoo(), mBar(mFoo) { 
  // ...
}
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/9a5W1j).

Comment: Hmmmm... is it just as easy? I thought that compiler first initialize all class data members according to constructor initializer list and only then it zero-initialize the rest data members. If you are right (and you are right) it means that compiler initialize all data members in order of their declaration with a rule, that those in constructor initializer list are initialized according to the list and the rest is zero-initialized. Am I right?

Comment: Everything should be initialized in their order of declaration. A member initializer list is a good way to enforce this.

Comment: cigien: I don't think that member initializer list has ability to "enforce" order of initialization. The data members are initializer in order of their declaration independently of their order in member initializer list.

Comment: @ViktorPlaček Right, "enforce" is a string word. I meant that if mem-initializer-lists conflict with order of declaration, then compilers are guaranteed to warn about it.

Comment: cigien: OK, now I am getting it. I have played a bit with godbolt pages you recommended me (BTW, very handy tool!) and found out that my compiler (gcc 8.1) does not raise warning when using uninitialized object (unlike clang). When you explicitly note expected initialization in mem-initializer-list as you recommended then even the gcc raise a warning about difference of initializations order. I did not notice that as I forgot to use -Wall parameter in my development environment (VS Code).
Thank you for your time for replying my question. The godbot tool was also very good hint.